# Monads, "container" exercise from sigfpe's blog

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm working my way through "Learn You a Haskell" and am now at the chapter on monads.  In other Haskell-related posts, I saw a number of folks recommend sigfpe's blog post on monads; it was highly recommended that a Haskell student go through his various exercises which allow the reader to "invent" / "discover" the concept of monads for himself/herself.

I'm having trouble with the last step of the set of exercises on containers.  I think it would be against forum rules to link to his site, so I'll do my best to describe it here.  (Lmk if I'm wrong on this front.)  As a heads up, my description of the exercise may not be entirely coherent so a simple google search may be best :)

Overview:

- Each set of exercises walks the reader through the step of constructing a different type of monad.  A general outline of the steps is as follows:

  - We consider two functions - `f'` and `g'` - which have the same type declaration
  - We construct a function (`bind`) which allows us to compose `f` and `g` such that the output is meaningful (probably makes more sense once you see the specific exercise below).  Straight composition doesn't work since the return type of `f` and `g` doesn't match their argument type.
  - Next, we define an identity function (`unit`) such that the following is true:
    `(bind unit . f') == (bind f' . unit)`
  - Based on the previous step, we define a `lift` function such that `lift f = unit . f`
  - In the last step, we are asked to show that the following holds true:
    `bind (lift f) (lift g) == lift . bind f g`

Here's the set of exercises I'm working on:

- We are asked to consider two functions `sqrt'` and `cbrt'` which calculate the square and cube roots of complex numbers (i.e., numbers of the form a + bi where a and b are real numbers and i is the square root of negative one).  The underlying math isn't important.  What's important is that the number of n-th roots possible is n.  In other words, a complex number (i.e., of the form a + bi) has  are two square roots of a complex number, three cube roots of a complex number, etc.
- Given the nature of complex roots, it makes sense that both `sqrt'` and `cbrt'` take an argument of type `Complex` and return type `[Complex]`.  We are asked to construct a `bind` function which lets us calculate the sixth root of a complex number while leveraging the fact that we already have sqrt' and cbrt'.  (Straight composition obv won't work)

  `bind :: (Complex -> [Complex) -> [Complex] -> [Complex]
   bind f = (concat . map f)`
- Next, we construct `unit` and `lift`:

  `unit :: Complex -> [Complex]
   unit x = [x]`

  `lift :: (Complex -> [Complex]) -> Complex -> [Complex]
   lift f = unit . f`
- In the last step (and this is what I'm having trouble with), we're asked to show the following:

  `bind (lift f) (lift g) == lift . bind f g`

First of all, doesn't the left-hand side of this equation have a type-mismatch in that `lift` can't accept an argument of type `[Complex]`?  Taking a step back, I'm not sure as to why we even bother defining `unit` and `lift`.  (My naive self thinks that the definition of `bind` solves the problem at hand therefore on to the next question.)   I'd greatly appreciate if someone could help me understand why we define these two functions and then seek to prove the very last equality.

---

As reference, am attaching my code below.  Please note that the `bind`, `unit` and `lift` functions have generalized type declarations.

```
bind :: (a1 -> [a]) -> [a1] -> [a]
bind f' = (concat . map f')

unit :: t -> [t]
unit x = [x]

lift :: (a -> b) -> a -> [b]
lift f = unit . f

--Definitions of cbRootC and sqRootC
data Complex = Complex Float Float deriving (Show)

cbrt' = rootC 3
sqrt' = rootC 2

rootC :: Float -> Complex -> [Complex]
rootC n (Complex a b) = zipWith Complex r i
            where r = map (* (mod ** (1/n) )) $ map cos $ map arg [0..n-1]
                  i = map (* (mod ** (1/n) )) $ map sin $ map arg [0..n-1]
                  arg  = ( * (2*pi / n) )
                  mod = sqrt (a*a + b*b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first misunderstanding is in the type of `lift`. In the description of the problem you list it as the first of the following, but in your code you have the second.

```
lift :: (Complex -> [Complex]) -> Complex -> [Complex]
lift :: (a       -> b        ) -> a       -> [b]
```

Notice how the second definition doesn't include `[]` around the return type of the first argument. The second one is correct. `lift` is going to take an ordinary function `Complex -> Complex` and produce a "multivalued" computation from it `Complex -> [Complex]`, which for the multiple values only returns the single value returned from the ordinary function.

Your second misunderstanding has to do with how `*` and `.` are used in [sigfpe's article](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html). `*` is used to compose "multivalued" computations together; `f * g = bind f . g`.  `.` is used for ordinary function composition.

You aren't asked to show that

```
bind (lift f) (lift g) == lift . bind f g
```

You are correct that this doesn't typecheck. Let's try for exercise. `bind` applied to two arguments returns `[a]`. `lift` applied to a single argument returns an `a1 -> [b]`

```
bind (lift f) (lift g) == lift . bind f g
[a]                    ~  a1 -> [b]
```

There's no choice of `a`, `a1`, and `b` that will make a list `[]` and function `->` have the same type.

Instead you are asked to show the following. Notice the different symbols `*` and `.`. We'll replace `*` with `bind` and `.`.

```
      lift f  *  lift g  == lift (f . g)
bind (lift f) . (lift g) == lift (f . g)
```

I'll leave the remainder of the exercise for you.

The reason `unit` and `lift` are useful is they allow you to reuse things of ordinary types that you already have. `lift` turns ordinary functions into "multivalued" computations and `unit` turns ordinary values into the results of "multivalued" computations.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed review and response.  I did indeed fail to see the distinction between `*` and `.`, as you pointed out.  I'm not sure I understand the RHS of the new equality, assuming that `f` and `g` are represented by `cbrt'` and `sqrt'` (as per the initial container exercises).  In particular, I thought that our very motivation for constructing the `bind` function was because we were unable to compose `f` and `g` directly with the `.` operator.  In other words, how can we have `(f . g)` in the RHS of the equation when `f` and `g` both have type `Complex -> [Complex]`?

Comment: `f` and `g` can't have those types. Let's just make up types for `f` and `g`: `f :: c -> d`, `g :: a -> b`. From `f . g` we can figure out two things: `b ~ c` and  `(f . g) :: a -> d`. `lift (f . g)` then has type `a -> [d]`. If we look at the LHS we can immediately see that `(lift g) :: a -> [b]` and `(lift f) :: c -> [d]`. `bind (lift f)` then has type `[c] -> [d]`, which, because `b ~ c` can be composed with `a -> [b]` to get an `a -> [d]`, the same type as the RHS.

Comment: Short answer: both `f` and `g` would have the type `Complex -> Complex`.

Comment: Proof of last equality makes sense.  Thanks again!  Last question from me (I promise!): how does this proof tie back to our motivation for this particular exercise, i.e., how do sqrt' and cbrt' fit into this last equality?  (Am asking since it's an important connection to make given the idea was to derive a monad based on the sqrt'/cbrt' problem.)

Comment: @DipakC there is indeed a way to compose *functions* like this and yes you can derive Monads from them too if you like - the [Kleisli-Operators](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-)

Comment: @DipakC Some of the exercises, like this one, are just proving along the way that the function debugging, "multivalued" computation, and random examples all obey some of the same laws.